# OleDb not implemented

Tags: c#, oledb, monodevelop

When running a very basic program, I get

> System.NotImplementedException (OleDb is not implemented.)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Tests
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is the cause for this. I am running this program on MonoDevelop on Linux, and when I run on Visual Studio it works.

Thank you for reading, help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: the cause would appear to be that OleDbConnection *is not implemented in mono on linux*; when you run in Visual Studio, you're presumably on .NET on Windows? What database are you *actually* connecting to? OLEDB is a "catch all" general purpose API, but there are often more specific providers for most sources - it is quite possible you can just change to the more specific provider (for example, `SqlConnection` for SQL Server, etc)

Comment: I updated my program to `SqlConnection` and the problem was fixed. Thank you @MarcGravell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the program to the `SqlConnection` library like @MarcGravell had offered and it works. It seems like the problem was in MonoDevelop.

Comment: MonoDevelop is not to blame here - that's the IDE. The IDE doesn't have any influence over what parts of the BCL are implemented.